# how to display message on APEX page from database procedure?

Tags: oracle-apex

I extremely need to know, how to display message on APEX page from database procedure?
I create procedure on my oracle db and create button on my APEX page and define dynamic action for  calling db procedure on my button in if condition i need some syntax instead DBMS_output for display dialogue box om my apex page.
if you know the answer please explain step by step because I don't have many experience in APEX especially in java script;

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_error.htm#BGBEEGIB

e.g.:

```
DECLARE
 sMsg VARCHAR2(40) := 'output':
BEGIN
  apex_error.add_error (
    p_message          => sMsg,
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );
END;
```

Comment: THANKS for reply according to your reference  apex_error.add_error is working on validation or process but I need use that on external procedure and call that procedure through dynamic action, if I don't understand please give an example. thanks again.